# On choosing the correct square root of $g^{4n}$ modulo primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, cryptography

Let $p$ be prime congruent to $3$ modulo $4$.

The discrete logarithm problem asks:  given $g,a,p$
such that $g^x \equiv a \pmod{p}$, find $x$.

Assume $g$ is of maximal multiplicative order.

In an attack on it, one may try to compute the square root
of $g^{2n}$, but the problem is there are two square
roots $g^n,-g^n$ and we don't know which one to choose.

For integer $n, 1 < n < (p-3)/4$, the correct square root
modulo $p$ of $g^{2n}$ is $g^n$.

**EDIT** Earlier revision asked about all $n$, but comments disproved it.

Define $f(a,p)=a^{\frac{p+1}{4}}$.

It is folklore that if $a$ is square $f(a,p)^2 \equiv a \pmod{p}$,
so $f$ computes one square root of $a$ and this might give
additional structure in choosing the root in the discrete logarithm.

We believe we the following hold.

1. $f(g^{4n},p) \equiv g^{2n} \pmod{p}$.
2. $f(g^{4n+2},p) \equiv -g^{2n+1} \pmod{p}$.
3. $f(g^{2n},p) \equiv (-g)^{n} \pmod{p}$.

In $g^n$ we can distinguish $n \mod 2$, but
can't find $n \mod 4$ to use (1) and (2).

On the other hand we have determinism of computing
the square root of $g^{4n}$ and we choose
the correct root from $g^{2n},-g^{2n}$.

We get experimental support for the claims and
try Pollard rho algorithm, but couldn't improve it.

> Q1 What is the intuition for computing the correct square root
> of $g^{4n}$

> Q2 Can we use the above for an attack of the discrete logarithm?

Comment: What is $n$? Any integer? An integer in $[0,(p-3)/4]$? What do you mean by the correct square root?

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Thanks. I edited with clarification about your comment.

Comment: The definition "For all positive integers $n$, the correct square root modulo $p$ of $g^{2n}$ is $g^n$ is problematic: $g^{2n} \equiv g^{2(n + (p-1)/2)}$ for any $n$, but $g^n \equiv -g^{n+(p-1)/2}$.

Comment: @BenSmith Thanks. Are you saying that (1) and (2) don't hold? Experimentally for p=31 they hold up to n=31^2.

Comment: The questions are too vague. Can you make them more specific?

Comment: I'm not saying anything about (1) and (2), I'm saying that the definition I quoted is incoherent.

Comment: (1) is straightforward, and (2) and (3) are consequences of $g$ being a generator (so $g^{(p-1)/2} = -1$).

Comment: @BenSmith Thanks, you have valid concerns about periodicity and "exponent overflow". Edited trying to fix the definition by assuming $ 1 < n < (p-3)/4$.